# Display only certain Shopify line items

Tags: line, shopify

This is for a Shopify site. Is there a way to display only certain line item properties in the cart? I have several and it looks messy so only want to display a chosen two or three.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming you have set up your line item properties similar to how it suggests on the Shopify wiki ([Line Item Properties](http://docs.shopify.com/support/your-store/6-products/how-do-I-collect-additional-information-on-the-product-page-Like-for-a-monogram-engraving-or-customization)).

You will have something like this in **product.liquid**:

```
<div>            
  <p><label for="property1">Property 1:</label></p>
  <p><input type="text" id="property1" name="properties[Property1]" /></p>
</div>
```

Then put this code in **cart.liquid**, beneath the cart item's title:

```
{% for p in item.properties %}
  {% if p.first == 'Property2' or p.first == 'Property5' %}
    {% unless p.last == blank %}
      {{ p.first }}:
      {% if p.last contains '/uploads/' %}
      <a class="lightbox" href="{{ p.last }}">{{ p.last | split: '/' | last }}</a>
      {% else %}
      {{ p.last }}
      {% endif %}
      <br />
    {% endunless %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The code above is straight from the [Line Item Properties](http://docs.shopify.com/support/your-store/6-products/how-do-I-collect-additional-information-on-the-product-page-Like-for-a-monogram-engraving-or-customization#updating-cart-liquid) article on the Shopify wiki (section 3.1 Displaying line item properties on the cart page). I've just added the if statement on the second line to only display the properties I want:

```
{% for p in item.properties %}
  {% if p.first == 'Property2' or p.first == 'Property5' %}
    ...
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Or, if you want to display several properties in a row (e.g. the first 3 properties), you could do it like this (without the if statement):

```
{% for p in item.properties limit:3 %}
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! I knew this had to be simple but just couldn't put it together. Appreciate your help!

Comment: No problems, happy to help :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, how can we make it work for checkout page? @StephSharp